# Powershell script to email an event

Tags: powershell

I am new to powershell and I am trying to write a script that will email me whenever someone moves or deletes a file or folder from a shared drive.  I already set up the task scheduler to execute the script when one of those events happen. The problem that I have is that I execute script from the shell it provides me with all the information regarding the last entry in the event logs. However, when it runs from the task scheduler it does not execute.  I believe that it has to do with the body line.  Any suggestions or insights will be greatly appreciated.

This is my code:

```
$events = Get-EventLog  -Logname Security -Newest 1

$From = $env:COMPUTERNAME + "@company.com"
$To = "me@company.com"
$Subject = $env:COMPUTERNAME + " " + $env:UserName + " " + $_.eventID
$Body =  $events | format-list -property * | out-string
$SMTPServer = "exch"

Send-MailMessage -From $From -to $To -Subject $Subject -Body $Body -SMTPServer $SMTPServer
```

Comment: Have you tried outputting the body to a file to see if the script is executing and you're getting expected output?  That might clue you into whether it's a problem with the `Send-MailMessage` versus a logic issue.

Comment: Also be sure that the task is running with your credentials.

Comment: It definitely does not display the body if I run it from the task but it does when I execute it from the shell.

Comment: I've had plenty of issues with scripts running fine, but error out when running as a scheduled tasks. Being we can't see everything you're doing, this can be hard to troubleshoot. Everything in your code seems pretty standard. You should read this article and verify some of the stuff he's mentioning: https://ramblingcookiemonster.github.io/Task-Scheduler/. Your issue could be related to the account running the scheduled task not able to send emails from the SMTP server, the account running the scheduled task not having LogOnAsBatchJob rights, etc.

Comment: Hi Shawn,  I don't think that it is access to the SMTP.  I am able to send emails with this script.  The problem is when the Task Scheduler executes the script it does not populate the email body with the log results.

Comment: I found what the problem was.  You have to select Run with the highest privilege in task scheduler for the script to run from there.  Thanks guys.

Comment: @Ren The reason you need to check run with the highest privilege is due to the permissions around the security log itself, by default a process must be running as admin to access the log.